# Non-type template argument evaluates to -1, which cannot be narrowed to type 'unsigned long long' xcode 4.6

Tags: ios, opencv, zxing, xcode4.6

I am using zxing and OpenCV lib in my project. I updated my XCode from 4.5 to 4.6 today and I am getting this error.

> externalLibs/boost/include/boost/gil/channel_algorithm.hpp:54:85:  Non-type template argument evaluates to -1, which cannot be narrowed to type 'unsigned long long'

And this error is on this line of code in one of the class of OpenCV Library:-

```
struct unsigned_integral_max_value : public mpl::
integral_c< UnsignedIntegralChannel,-1> {};
```

On Earlier version of Xcode its working fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: whats your question? this is a statement ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems boost doesn't like c++ 11 support added with the new clang compiler

so.. it say disable c++ 11 support in build settings
[image]

= src: see https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/7270

Answer (score 0):

The max value of an unsigned long long variable is in hex 0xFFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF, i.e. all bits are 1's. If interpreted as a signed number, this corresponds to a -1. So often programmers  use -1 instead, hoping that the compiler will not complain. Apparently, this did not happen in XCode 4.5, but 4.6 does more rigorous checking...

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same error when compiling on macOS Sierra with `Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)` and `-std=c++11`. To solve the problem I included the following compiler flag: `-Wno-error=c++11-narrowing`